# php: $a=$b OR $a=$c vs. ternary

Tags: php, variable-assignment, ternary-operator, boolean-logic, assignment-operator

I need to assign one of two variables to a third variable, using the value of the second variable if the first is (bool)false or undefined.

I usually do this using ternary notation like so:

```
$foobar = ($some_prefix_and_some_variable_name) ? $some_prefix_and_some_variable_name : $bar ;
```

but sometimes this is not so pretty if the $foo variable name is very long, as it needs to be repeated in this notation.

My question is now, is it just as good to use this notation:

```
$foobar = $some_prefix_and_some_variable_name OR $foobar = $bar;
```

and is this notation interchangeable with the ternary version?

Comment: If the variable name is too long for use with an expression like this, the variable name is probably too long altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$foobar = $foo OR $foobar = $bar;` evaluates to this:

Assign foo to foobar. 
* Is there a value there?
   * If not, assign bar to foobar.

While the other evaluates to:

Is there a value at foo?
* If so assign foobar = foo
* else assign foobar = bar

In the first example, if !foo you are assigning twice, if foo it can be faster. In the second example, you are only setting the value once total. I'll wager though that the speed difference is negligible.

The bigger issue here is readability. If 5.3 short notation isn't available, then I would still use the ternary notation if only because other programmers expect it.

For that matter, you will save more time and money by using the traditional ternary syntax if only because when people see your code they won't be asking themselves, WTF?

Comment: Thanks, you sum up all the answers here, and politely elaborate on why it is (faster/slower, a bad idea, etc..)

Comment: Not a problem. I've recently realized that thorough answers, even if not first, will still be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

In PHP 5.3 there is also the short ternary notation:

```
$foobar = $fooooooooooooooooooooooooo ?: $bar ;
```

Comment: pretty handy, didn't know, but need to support a little further back.

Comment: This notation is so misleading.

Answer (score 4):

Since PHP 5.3 there is a special operator for this:

```
$foobar = $fooooooooooooooooooooooooo ?: $bar;
```

From the [documentation on the ternary operator](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.

Comment: +1 (For the link and excerpt) Sort of a shame that a short-circuit logical OR doesn't behave the same way. Silly designs.

Comment: @pst: I didn't understand that now. As far as I know the `OR` would behave just the same. (Wouldn't it?)

Comment: Not in PHP :( `false or "hello"` evaluates to `true`, not `"hello"` (it would evaluate to `"hello"` in Ruby and Python, for instance, and has to do with language design). Ruby and Python's "or" therefore works like `?:`-short in PHP.

Comment: @pst: Oh sorry, I didn't understand what you mean ^^ Yes, you're right - we all know that PHP's not perfect. (Well, okay, not even nearly perfect.)

Answer (score 1):

in matter of speed, this:

```
$foobar = $fooooooooooooooooooooooooo OR $foobar = $bar;
```

it's faster

Comment: Still logically need to evaluate $foooooooo, as well as an assignment. I call shenanigans.

Comment: That makes me want to cry. Please don't hide side-effect in EXPRESSIONS for a meager micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

No.
I don't know for sure whether the two notations are interchangeable, which means that you should not use the second one! Whether or not they are actually the same, if it is not immediately clear what the code does (as in this case), you should change it, unless you are absolutely sure that no one else will ever have to update this code. If I saw that written, I wouldn't be sure whether it was supposed to be like this, or whether there was some typo, and the bug was simply never discovered (seen it too many times!).

Ideally, with very long variable names, you should do this:

```
if($fooooooooooooooooooooooooo){
    $foobar =$fooooooooooooooooooooooooo;
} else {
    $foobar = $bar;
}
```

Just to make it easy to read, unless speed is of the essence, in which case you should use the ternary operator.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is supposed to be easier to read -- the statements off each of the IF branches *are not structured the same* which makes it *harder* to read, IMOHO. Be consistent.

Comment: @pst They are structured the same. It's just for the purposes of illustration. It is easier to read an if statement (if(a){x=y} else x=z) than to read a statement of the form (x=y or x=z). Again, just an example.

Comment: I disagree that they are structured the same. In the `then` there is the `{ }` and extra new lines. In the `else` there is neither. Compare with the "uniformly structured" cases: `if ($foo) $foo = $bar;\nelse $foo = $quz;` or `if ($foo) {\n  $foo = $bar;\n} else {\n  $foo = $quz;\n}\n` -- I find that *consistency* can *help* greatly with writing correct and maintainable code.

Comment: That's not pedanticism; it's perfectionism, and in a programmer it's a damned good trait... for the reasons that pst himself gave. There's no excuse to be lazy.